# How give same element for input and output parameter in wsdl?

Tags: java, web-services, xsd, wsdl, jax-ws

I have aa.xsd as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://wwwtest.com/test" xmlns:abc="http://wwwtest.com/test">

    <xs:simpleType name="APP_TYPE">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="ABC" />
            <xs:enumeration value="DEF" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name="RootElement" type="abc:RootElementType" />
    <xs:complexType name="RootElementType">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="abc:UserRequest" />
                <xs:any minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="abc:UserResponse" />
                <xs:any minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="UserRequest" type="abc:UserRequestType" />
    <xs:complexType name="UserRequestType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="UserLoginName" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element ref="abc:VendorApp" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="VendorApp" type="abc:VendorAppType" />
    <xs:complexType name="VendorAppType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="AppName" type="abc:APP_TYPE" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="UserResponse" type="abc:UserResponseType" />

    <xs:complexType name="UserResponseType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="SessionKey" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="SessionKeyExpDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Wrote the WSDL as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="ABCcomacc" targetNamespace="http://wwwtest.com/test/com/acc/" xmlns:abc="http://wwwtest.com/test" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:ws="http://wwwtest.com/test/com/acc/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="http://wwwtest.com/test" schemaLocation="aaa.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

    <wsdl:message name="xyzSearchRequest">
        <wsdl:part element="abc:RootElement" name="parameters"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:message name="xyzSearchResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="abc:RootElement" name="parameters"/>
    </wsdl:message>

    <wsdl:portType name="ABCcomacc">
        <wsdl:operation name="xyzSearch">
            <wsdl:input message="ws:xyzSearchRequest"/>
            <wsdl:output message="ws:xyzSearchResponse"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>

    <wsdl:binding name="ABCcomaccSOAP12" type="ws:ABCcomacc">

        <soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

        <wsdl:operation name="xyzSearch">
            <soap12:operation soapAction="http://wwwtest.com/test/com/acc/xyzSearch"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap12:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>

    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="ABCcomacc">
        <wsdl:port binding="ws:ABCcomaccSOAP12" name="ABCcomaccSOAP12">
            <soap12:address location="http://localhost:9080/ABCcomacc/ABCcomacc"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

My skeleton class implementation generating as below.

```
@javax.jws.WebService (endpointInterface="com.wwwtest.test.com.acc.ABCcomacc", targetNamespace="http://wwwtest.com/test/com/acc/", serviceName="ABCcomacc", portName="ABCcomaccSOAP12", wsdlLocation="WEB-INF/wsdl/LTCCommonAccord.wsdl")
@javax.xml.ws.BindingType (value=javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
public class ABCcomaccSOAP12Impl{

    public void xyzSearch(Holder<RootElementType> parameters) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return;
    }

}
```

This method return type is `void` and method argument is `Holder<RootElementType> parameters` but return type and method argument should be  RootElementType.

could any one have the idea why I'm getting this output. please advice me...
I'm using JAX-WS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have different names for request and response elements like below.
`<wsdl:message name="xyzSearchRequest">
     <wsdl:part element="abc:RootElement" name="reqparams"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="xyzSearchResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="abc:RootElement" name="respparams"/>
    </wsdl:message>`

How are you generating bindings ? If you using wsimport goal from maven, then write a binding file and add below in bindings section.
`<enableWrapperStyle>false</enableWrapperStyle>`